# EditText new "row" after 25 characters

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my EditText view to append a new "row" and not just a space between the characters when reaching 25.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/quote_field"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:maxLength="70"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:imeActionLabel="Send"
        android:inputType="text"
        fontPath="fonts/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

then in Java I have a TextWatcher:

```
private class textChangeListener implements TextWatcher{
    EditText textView;
    private textChangeListener(EditText v){
        this.textView = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String input = textView.getText().toString();
        if(input.length() == 25 && !isReached){
            System.out.println("NEW LINE");
            textView.append("\n");
            isReached=true;
        }
        if(input.length() < 25 && isReached){
            isReached=false;
        }
    }
}
```

the "\n" is only appending a "space" and not a new row. So I assume that's where it all fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
android:ems="12"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: "android:inputType="textMultiLine" " solved it! Thanks!